# How to call getItem() & getOptionList()in an Observer.php

Tags: php, cart, custom-options

I have an observer and would like to get the selected custom options array.

I have found the two elements I require in:

```
app/design/frontend/MY-THEME/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Which are:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_options = $this->getOptionList();
```

I just don't know how to get them in an observer i.e. what else I have to call.

Comment: what event are you observing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your observer method looks something like this:

```
public function doSomething($observer)
{
    ...
}
```

If so, you can get the item like this:

```
$_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
```

and you can get the options like this:

```
$options = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration')->getCustomOptions($_item); //where $_item is the result of the previous line.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to call specifically 'getOptionList();' which unfortunately is not working. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If I use: 
$options = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration')->getOptionList($_item);

I get:

Call to undefined method MageWorx_CustomOptions_Helper_Product_Configuration::getOptionList()

Comment: The method name is `getCustomOptions` not `getOptionList`

Comment: The method I require is [getoptionlist()](http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html) which works fine in:

app/design/frontend/MY-THEME/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

I just need to know how to use it in an observer. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use the exact method because that one is available only in that block. I gave you an alternative. The method in the template you mentioned is basically a wrapper for what I suggested.

Comment: Thank you @Marius, I think I understand. In this case the $options array is being returned empty??

Comment: I'll double check when I get to a computer

Comment: Got it to work, you were exactly right! Many thanks!!